# FluentNHibernate Mapping .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm have a issue, 
i'm studyng nhibernate with c# and .net core, but i dont know how to procede on this case.
i create my table with 2FK:

```
 public class Venda
{
    public Venda()
    {
        VendaId = Guid.NewGuid();
        DataVenda = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public virtual Guid VendaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid BombomId { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid ClienteId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DataVenda { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Bombom> Bomboms { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
}
```

My migration is

```
   [FluentMigrator.Migration(2)]
public class CreateTableVenda : FluentMigrator.Migration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Create.Table("Venda")
            .WithColumn("VendaId").AsGuid().NotNullable().PrimaryKey().Indexed()
            .WithColumn("DataVenda").AsDateTime().NotNullable()
            .WithColumn("BombomId").AsGuid().NotNullable().Indexed()
            .WithColumn("ClienteId").AsGuid().NotNullable().Indexed();

        Create.ForeignKey().FromTable("Venda").ForeignColumn("BombomId")
          .ToTable("Bombom").PrimaryColumn("BombomId");

        Create.ForeignKey().FromTable("Venda").ForeignColumn("ClienteId")
        .ToTable("Cliente").PrimaryColumn("ClienteId");
    }
    public override void Down()
    {
        Delete.Table("Venda");
    }

}
```

But my mapping, i'm have issues, because i want to LAZYLOAD the map entity together when i get

```
public class VendaMap : ClassMap<Venda>
{
    public VendaMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.VendaId);
        Map(x => x.DataVenda);
        Map(x => x.BombomId).Column("Bombom").Access.CamelCaseField();
        Map(x => x.ClienteId);            
        LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

Could someone help me please?